# Button Click Event

Tags: vb.net, button, click, release, eventhandler

I have a quick question about the button.click event in VB.NET.

What I'm trying to do is write a piece of code which will run a loop while an on screen button is pressed, and stop running code when it is released.

For example, it will toggle a picturebox between two colors while the button is pressed, and stop toggling colors when the button is released (I dont want to do this, but it is a useful example).

How would one accomplish this? The Button.Click event only fires after you have clicked AND released the button, whereas I need to separate these two into a click handler and a release handler.

Cheers

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Oh that was stupid, VB.NET, I'll update it now. Cheers.

Comment: Well to be honest, I know nothing of VB.NET, but I found this site: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/NET/nets10p2.html, which might provide some help for you. You could have a while loop like in this pseudo-code:
onButtonClick:
    while(button.isClicked):
        (do something here)
   -Edit: the way comments are formatted makes it look ugly, but you should get the main idea.

Comment: Well, full day of searching later, seems you found the one site I  missed. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a button for this (you can if you want to), I would use a panel and a timer. Here is and example: (I will explain after)

Let's assume our timer is called `ButtonTimer` and our panel is called `EventPanel`

Let's also use the example you gave. Let's call our PictureBox `AltPicturebox`

Set the `ButtonTimer.Interval` to 1 and `ButtonTimer.Enabled` to True

```
Private Sub ButtonTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e as EventArgs) Handles ButtonTimer.Tick
    Select Case(MouseButtons)
        Case MouseButtons.Left 'checks if left mouse click is down
            If (MousePosition.X > EventPanel.Left) & (MousePosition.X < EventPanel.Right) & (MousePosition.Y > EventPanel.Top) & (MousePosition.Y < EventPanel.Bottom) Then 'checks if mouse is within the EventPanel control
                AltPictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Image1.png") 'sets the image of picturebox
        Case Else
            AltPictureBox.Image = Imag.FromFile("C:\OriginalImage.png")
    End Select
End Sub
```

Hope this helped,

Rodit